# KineticJS: make dropped elements be draggable as a Kinetic.Group

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, kineticjs

Well.. so it's the same problem that I face with `Kinetic.Group`. I tried several things to make this work, but always the same result: it does not work, and even worse, the basic drag and drop functionality disappears!

I already know how to do this inside **one** container, the difficulty comes when I try to adapt it to the drag and drop **from DOM to container**. After the drop, I need the images and shapes to be moved all together. That's why I created a group for each item and made it draggable.

This is the fiddle I'm changing to make the dropped elements in the canvas, be draggable as a whole group (the non-working fiddle) http://jsfiddle.net/gkefk/15/. What is wrong with this code?

*PS1:* this one is the main functionality of drag and drop http://jsfiddle.net/gkefk/14/ which I'm editing.

*PS2:* I'm a beginner, so if you find "stupidities" in that code, please report.

Comment: Get rid of jQuery altogether, don't use it or it's plug-ins, you need a canvas only implementation here so that your DOM is not modified. That's the 'stupidity/mistake' that you are making. When you use jQuery UI to do the drag/drop for you, you are modifying the DOM, which makes your canvas not work properly.

Comment: It's okay to use just the accordion jquery ui, isn't it?

Comment: I recommend not using it, as it will still interfere with the kineticjs implementation of things.

Comment: yeah? But I need to put the items in a certain logical order, and divide them (equipments, sensors and building features) :/ Do you have any suggestion on how to do that?

Comment: That can be added later, first get original problem to work correctly, later you can group with an accordion implementation in kineticjs. Later you will dynamically create a layer on the left side, which contains multiple groups, and the ability to show/hide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple guide how to get what you want out of this:

Get rid of jQuery and start over.

```
1. Create a new Stage
2. Create two layers, one taking up the left half of the Stage, the other the right half.
3. put all your objects on the left side, make them clone-able on mousedown and fire the drag event so you can place them in the other layer on mouse up.
4. if your item is a rectangle - I'm assuming this is a group which is will have children, create a new group, and a rectangle inside it, place it in the right layer on drop.
5. if your item is a house, check for mouse intersection with a rectangle, if mouse is over a rectangle, get the parent of the rectangle on drop (which will be a group), and then place the house in that group, else place in right layer freely.
```

Comment: I'll follow those steps and tell you if I find difficulties (sorry in advance :p) I guess I've been messing too much with my code.

Comment: no need to be sorry, you were trying to use two very different libraries together, which are used for very different things. KineticJS is for Canvas, while JQueryUI modifies the DOM.

Comment: Hey @EliteOctagon .. I have this issue now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707636/kineticjs-drag-and-drop-from-one-layer-to-another

Comment: Your rectangle should be in a new group when you create it, then you can check for intersections when you try to place the house in it, so your house and rectangle will be in the same group. that way, when you drag the rectangle, you will also drag the house.